# excel - strip fields containing apostrophe

Tags: excel

I have two cells in my excel sheet, where I compare them against each other.

Now, it's a long sheet, and I have formatted all the date cells to "Short Date". However, some dates are entered like below:

```
'02-02-2015
```

And others are entered without the ':

```
02-02-2015
```

Now, the problem is when I compare those two dates above - it doesn't give me the correct result, because of the " **'** "

How can I "strip" all the date fields to not use the apostrophe in front?

Thanks.

Comment: @pnuts enough with the stalking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try converting both to one type when comparing them
, e.g. `TEXT`

Example

```
=IF(TEXT(A1;)=TEXT(B1;);1;0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Replace`

Example:

```
Dim D As Date: D = Replace("'20-01-2015", "'", "")
```

Comment: How can I apply this to only two columns? Remember each cell in the columns have different dates..

Comment: I've giving you VBA solution. Use "=Replace" formula if you want to do it without VBA.

Answer (score 0):

With data in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=IF(LEFT(A1,1)="'",MID(A1,2,9999),A1)
```

and copy down.  For example:

[image]